# Truth Table Construction explanation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm studying propositional logic I'm new into this lesson I already know some of the basics but can you explain the "p v ¬ q" column part why it became T,T,F,T and also p v ¬ q → q why it became T,F,T,F

Here's the link:
https://image.prntscr.com/image/jSqaBKc0SKmQkwcXHUYevg.png

Comment: The rightmost column is built up from that for $p \lor \lnot q$ and that for $q$ using the truth table for the connective $\to$ : $T \to T$ is $T$; $T \to F$ is $F$, and so on.

Comment: Is bracket or parenthesis necessary to put on?

Comment: We know that ¬P is called the denial of P. It will make the opposite value of the original P like P is true in the first row. ¬P is false. P v Q is called the disjunction of P and Q. P or Q. What does it say? We will have the P v Q true only if either P or Q posses truth value.Your case p v ¬ q, we must have either p or  ¬ q to be true.
What I learn is that P→ Q. This is called the conditional statement.If P, then Q. For this statement to be true we must have the either true Q or false P. To explain your stuff, p v ¬ q → q. EIther p v ¬ q is false or q is true. that is why we have the result.

Answer (score 0):

Constructing a truth table for a compound propositional statement starts with assigning T/F to the unknown simple proposition unknown letter variables, and breaking down your statement so that each part (brackets, logical connectives, negations) is handled in a column of the table.

Your compound statement is $(p \vee \neg  q) \rightarrow q$. So you begin by assigning values to $p$ and $q$ and then 'work' the expression. You see a $\neg  q$ so you make that column 3. You know how the truth table for disjunction works, so you can now fill in column 4 for $p \vee \neg  q$. You simply look at column 1 and column 3 to pick up the values for $p$ and $\neg q$. Do not get upset with seeing a negation, you're just looking at

$p \vee (\neg q)$

and plugging it into the 'placeholders' of your basic disjunction truth table.

There is nothing wrong about using brackets liberally to help see what is going on. As you get better, you will find yourself going into 'autopilot' mode as you breakdown expressions and fill in the truth tables.

As for the final column, you must have handy the basic truth table for the conditional implication connective, $s \rightarrow t$. You will be plugging in column 4 for $s$ and column 2 for $q$.